# Shortest path in graph in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm trying to calculate the shortest path in a graph stored in CouchDB. I have to do it 'in db' because my task is to compare query speeds in various situations for 3 different DBMSs. So loading the data and running dijkstra in python (or anything else) is not an option. I'm pretty new to document based databases so I may be wrong but as I see it my only option is a view.

My db structure is the following:

- One document represents one graph.
- In the document with a key 'edges' there is an array of objects with 3 properties: start, end, distance.
- **start** and **end** are node IDs but there is no other interesting information about nodes so they are not stored anywhere else.
- **distance** is a float

My idea was to create a view that returns the shortest path. I have this code for calculating it. It is based on [this](https://medium.com/@adriennetjohnson/a-walkthrough-of-dijkstras-algorithm-in-javascript-e94b74192026) post. I just had to modify a bit otherwise I got syntax errors for stuff like **let,foreach**:

```
function (doc) {
  function Graph() {
    this.nodes = [];
    this.adjacencyList = {};

    this.addNode = function(node) {
      if(this.nodes.indexOf(node) != -1)
        return;
      this.nodes.push(node); 
      this.adjacencyList[node] = [];
    }

    this.addEdge = function(node1, node2, weight) {
      this.adjacencyList[node1].push({node:node2, weight: weight});
      //this.adjacencyList[node2].push({node:node1, weight: weight});
    }

    this.shortestPath = function(startNode, endNode){
      var times = {};
      var backtrace = {};
      var pq = new PriorityQueue();

      times[startNode] = 0;

      for(var i = 0; i<this.nodes.length; i++){
        if(this.nodes[i] != startNode){
          times[node] = Infinity;
        }
      }

      pq.enqueue([startNode, 0]);

      while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        var shortestStep = pq.dequeue();
        var currentNode = shortestStep[0];
        for(var i=0;i< this.adjacencyList[currentNode].length; i++){
          var neighbor = this.adjacencyList[currentNode][i];
          var time = times[currentNode] + neighbor.weight;
          if (time < times[neighbor.node]) {
            times[neighbor.node] = time;
            backtrace[neighbor.node] = currentNode;
            pq.enqueue([neighbor.node, time]);
          }
        }
      }
      var path = [endNode];
      var lastStep = endNode;
      while(lastStep !== startNode) {
        path.unshift(backtrace[lastStep]);
        lastStep = backtrace[lastStep];
      }

      return 'Path is ${path} and time is ${times[endNode]}';
    }
  };

  function PriorityQueue() {
    this.collection = [];

    this.enqueue = function(element){
      if (this.isEmpty()){ 
        this.collection.push(element);
      } else {
        var added = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= this.collection.length; i++){
          if (element[1] < this.collection[i-1][1]){ 
            this.collection.splice(i-1, 0, element);
            added = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!added){
            this.collection.push(element);
        }
      }
    };

    this.dequeue = function() {
      var value = this.collection.shift();
      return value;
    };

    this.isEmpty = function() {
      return (this.collection.length === 0) 
    };
  };

  var graph = new Graph();

  var startNode = 118;
  var endNode = 270;
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.edges.length; ++i) {
    graph.addNode(doc.edges[i].start);
    graph.addNode(doc.edges[i].end);
    graph.addEdge(doc.edges[i].start,doc.edges[i].end,doc.edges[i].distance);
  }

  emit("shortest", graph.shortestPath(startNode,endNode));
}
```

However when querying the view I get 0 rows.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example dataset:

```
{
  "_id": "7c75c647957f57eaa47103d5795eab44",
  "_rev": "3-4c8bc32cf6129209b1ce2fec35f6e6cd",
  "edges": [
    {
      "start": "1609",
      "end": "1622",
      "distance": 57.403187
    },
    {
      "start": "2471",
      "end": "2479",
      "distance": 29.718756
    },
    {
      "start": "2463",
      "end": "2471",
      "distance": 61.706902
    },
    {
      "start": "2443",
      "end": "2448",
      "distance": 19.080025
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: One document represents one graph, or one document represents one node?

Comment: One document is one graph. As I mentioned there are nk nodes saved because the only Interesting thing about them is their id so they only appear in edges’ start and end properties

Comment: Can you provide an example graph document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found it. When I rewrote the foreach to a traditional for, I forgot to change this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<this.nodes.length; i++){
    if(this.nodes[i] != startNode){
      times[node] = Infinity;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<this.nodes.length; i++){
   if(this.nodes[i] != startNode){
      times[this.nodes[i]] = Infinity;
   }
}
```

Interestingly I did not see any error in CouchDB. I had to run my code locally with node.js to find out there was an error.